# Execution Context: Why would this javascript code behave like this?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have started learning about asynchronous programming in javascript.
Please take a look at the following code:

```js
const myPromise = () => Promise.resolve('I have resolved');

function firstFunction() {
  myPromise().then(res => console.log(res));
  console.log('firstFunction');
}

async function secondFunction() {
  console.log(await myPromise());
  console.log('secondFunction');
}

firstFunction()
secondFunction();
```

This code will produce the following output:

- firstFunction
- I have resolved
- I have resolved
- secondFunction

I am happy with the output and I think I do understand why this is happening:

- FirstFunction() goes to the call stack
- The promise will be set aside on the event loop
- console.log('firstFunction') runs and it is printed (firstFunction)
- Now the call stack is empty, therefore the resolved promise prints (I have resolved)
- Next SecondFunction() goes to the call stack
- Since we i am using Async await the code will wait for myPromise()
- Then will print (I have resolved)
- And finally it will print (secondFunction)

When I change the above code to be like the following:

```js
const myPromise = () => Promise.resolve('I have resolved');

function sayHi() {
  console.log('hi');
}

function firstFunction() {
  myPromise().then(res => console.log(res));
  console.log('firstFunction');
}

async function secondFunction() {
  console.log(await myPromise());
  console.log('secondFunction');
}

firstFunction()
secondFunction();
sayHi();
```

I would expect the code to output the following:

- firstFunction
- I have resolved
- I have resolved
- secondFunction
- hi

But instead the code outputs:

- firstFunction
- hi
- I have resolved
- I have resolved
- secondFunction

Could you please explain me this code behaviour?

Comment: I think your question can be simplified to -> `why is Hi not shown last`.  And the answer is because there is nothing in your code saying to wait for `firstFunction` & `secondFunction` to finish, it's as simple as that.

Comment: "_Now the call stack is empty_", that is where you are wrong. Both `firstFunction` and `secondFunction` are part of an anonymous frame that need to complete before the next iteration of the event loop will start.

Comment: This is the bit I was missing : Both firstFunction and secondFunction are part of an anonymous frame that need to complete before the next iteration of the event loop will start. Thanks Ivar for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the message queue to execute the stored messages (from async functions), the call stack **needs to be empty**.

You can check out this [article](https://dev.to/kapantzak/js-illustrated-the-event-loop-4mco) about the event loop that illustrates this behaviour.

In the second case, the call stack has 3 functions which need to be executed and be removed from it, before the messsages inside the message queue get executed, so the `hi` has to be printed before the async calls.

`secondFunction` gets executed last because its inside an async function and there is an await before it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the numbers for the following:

1 - firstFunction()

2 - secondFunction();

3 - sayHi();

`Hi` is printed second in the list because it's quicker to get to number 3 than it is to resolve the promises. Because the `console.log()` in number 1 isn't in a promise, it executes immediately and in turn happens before the `hi` message.

1, 2 and 3 are all executed but because the promise values in 1 and 2 take x ms longer to resolve, Hi is printed before any promise based console logs.

Answer (score 0):

Annotated with comments:

```
function firstFunction() {
  myPromise().then(res => console.log(res)); // this console.log will be called 
                                             //after myPromise() is _resolved_
  console.log('firstFunction');              // this console.log will be called 
                                             // after function myPromise() is _called_
}

async function secondFunction() {
  console.log(await myPromise()); // again, not gonna console.log until myPromise()
                                  // is resolved...
  console.log('secondFunction');  // and any subsequent line isn't going to be executed
                                  // until `await` is complete
}
```